# Build dynamic predicate in run time according to user selections

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, runtime

I am building a form to show a list that will be filter based on user conditions in my WinForm application,
suppose i have a generic list `IList<Order>` and `Order`
has some properties such as `OrderId`,`CustomerName`,`CreationDate`,...

```
public Class Order
{
 public string OrderId {get; set;}
 public string CustomerName {get; set;}
 public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
}
```

also, i put some controls in my form to user could filter the list. a `TextBox` for `OrderId` another for `CustomerName` and two `DateTimePickers` for `CreationDate` Range(FromDateTimePicker,ToDateTimePicker).

also i defined a predicate variable as:

```
Func<Order, bool> predicate = null;
```

now how can i build my `predicate` according to user input values?

i tried to write this code:

```
if (tbOrderId.Text != string.Empty)
{
   string orderId;
   predicate = t=>t.OrderId == orderId;
}
if(tbCustomerName.Text != string.Empty)
{
   string customer = tbCustomerName.Text;
   if(predicate!=null)
      predicate = predicate && (t=>t.CustomerName == customer);
   else
      predicate = (t=>t.CustomerName == customer);
}
....
```

but i get this error:

```
Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Func<Order,bool>' and 'lambda expression'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you're not actually applying the `&&` to the result of the predicate, you're applying it to the predicate itself. Even if you were to write it like this:

```
predicate = t => predicate(t) && t.CustomerName == customer;
```

It would compile, but you'd end up with an infinite recursion.

For simplicity, you could simply do this using pure Linq (will work with any `IEnumerable<T>`):

```
IEnumerable<Order> results = ... // all items

if (tbOrderId.Text != string.Empty)
{
   string orderId;
   results = results.Where(t => t.OrderId == orderId);
}

if (tbCustomerName.Text != string.Empty)
{
   string orderId;
   results = results.Where(t => t.CustomerName == customer);
}
```

Or this using expressions (works well with `IQueryable<T>`):

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DateTime));
Expression predicate = Expression.Constant(true);

if (tbOrderId.Text != string.Empty)
{
   string orderId = tbOrderId.Text;
   Expression prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "OrderId");
   Expression filter = Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(orderId));
   predicate = Expression.AndAlso(predicate, filter);
}

if(tbCustomerName.Text != string.Empty)
{
   string customer = tbCustomerName.Text;
   Expression prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "CustomerName");
   Expression filter = Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(customer))
   predicate = Expression.AndAlso(predicate, filter);
}

Expression lambda = Expression.Lambda(predicate, parameter);
return results.Where(lambda);
```